# Can I rewrite a URL without redirecting?

Tags: javascript, url, .htaccess

So I learned from [this handy guide](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/) how to use `.htaccess` to redirect pretty URIs like `foobar.com/baz` to specific content that may reside at `foobar.com/bazheader345.php?user=baz`.

What if I'd like to do the opposite? My anchors are static but I have a lot of content in different files - and none of them has a particularly pretty name. Say I have a page at `foobar.com` called `123.html` and would like the location bar to remain `http://foobar.com` *despite* the navigation between files that the user does.

Can this be done via changes to `.htaccess`? Or simply Javascript?

If it *is* possible, would it interfere with the browser's history states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really easy to do with [HTML frames](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_frames.asp). Let's say your home page is `http://example.com/index.html`. Save `index.html` as `home.html` and save something like the following in `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="home.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
  </body>
</html>
```

If you don't want to rename your original home page, you could instead stick a [`DirectoryIndex` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) in your `.htaccess` file. Just save the above code in, say, `frame.html`, change `home.html` to whatever filename your index is at, and add:

```
DirectoryIndex frame.html
```

to your `.htaccess` file.

However, you should know that this practice fell out of style over 10 years ago because it has inherent problems. It won't break your history, but it breaks [deep linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking) (that is, one can't bookmark or link to anything other than the home page).

More info:

- [Frames Suck Most of the Time](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/9612.html)
- [Why Are Frames So Evil?](http://www.html-faq.com/htmlframes/?framesareevil)
- [Framing Critique on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_(World_Wide_Web)#Critique)

Comment: I agree. While maintaining a consistent URL is more or less possible, it is not normally a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You would be much better off creating pretty names for all those other pages, so that you allow your users to **link** to or **bookmark** those other pages.... or keep the ugly urls and don't worry about it.

Keeping the same url and displaying different content defeats the entire purpose of a URL, which is to be a **unique** address for a specific set of information.

Comment: I accepted Mark Trapp's answer for posterity, because it provides a method to achieve the goal in question, however, for the record, you are right.